# Are block and partition synonyms in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I know that `block` is the basic unit of storage, while `partition` is the basic unit of computation in Spark.

**Does one partition map to one block**?

Besides, suppose the storage level is `DISK_ONLY`, will one `block` be saved as one file in disk?

Comment: It's written [here](https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/apache-spark-blocks-explained/read) that one partition of an rdd corresponds to one block. As to whether one block is saved as one file, it seems to depend on BlockManager although by default it seems to be the case.